# Best way to auto-close broken json and maintain nesting

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

I have some broken json strings.

How would I detect and close broken objects/arrays as needed, while keeping order and any nested data.

Here are some unit test in/outputs:

```
[
    {input:"( )[ ]",output:"( )[ ]"},
    {input:"]-(",output:"[]-()"},
    {input:"} { [()] (()v()) } ])",
    output:"([{} { [()] (()v()) } ])"},
    {input:"", output:""},
    {input:"([{]]}", output: "ERROR"},
]
```

Is there a clean way to do this in javascript?

Comment: @Bravo yes, some js function

Comment: think of it as just a string, not exact json